# Automatic animation after previous in Unity- how to do something like that?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Automatic animation after the previous one in Unity - how to do something like that?

I mean, in my game, I performed the jump function and it has its animations, and how do you do that when it ends, the falling animation will start - that is, right after the jump animation,
Question: How can I start the animation immediately after two in Unity?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Unity's built in animator this is actually really easy to do without any code. All you have to do is setup a transition to the next animation after that animation plays. I'd recommend [this](https://youtu.be/gON_hhhvheI?t=122) tutorial to get started. (I've already set it to start at the part of the video where he actually talks about it)